# Why font size does not change?

Tags: css, font-size

I want to set font size with `em`, not `px`. Here is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

div{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
</style>

<body>
<div>hello world</div>
</body>
```

I want to set `div` font size to be 12px, but it looks small than I expect, I disable `div` style with chrome browser tools, it does not look to have any change. What should I do to make `div` font size 12px?

Comment: Have you tried `font-size:12px`?

Comment: If you don't have other CSS, the current CSS can set div's font size to 12px correctly. You could check its computed style by using Firefox's Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools to confirm that.

Comment: @IanY, yes, In `computed style`, it shows the font-size of `div` is 12px, thx very much.

Comment: @IanY, I just change `div` font-size to a very small number:`.2em`, but in `computed style`, it still shows `12px`, does it mean that the smallest font-size in browser is `12px`? If not, how `12px` was computed?

Comment: @HiwayChe, Chrome prevents font size from dropping below 12px by default. That's why you couldn't notice changes. To overcome that, set `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;` on the `body`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as no-repro since it does change in your example; you just did not notice initially.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

hmm, seems to work for me: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/thinkfast2008/HKtC7/1/)

Though, what you might be referring to is *little* change from enabling/disabling the `font-size` property. This is because the `em` for nested elements is relative to their parents `font-size`. In your instance, the `font-size:Xem` for the div is relative to the `font-size:X%` of the body.

If your still getting no change, try setting your `body`'s `font-size` to a larger percentage to make your `div`'s font larger

Comment: yes, you are right. The change is very _little_, when I change `div` to a larger size, it can be detected distinctly.

Comment: Thank you for the link example. I am learning to use EM, which I needed to get started. You Rock, Michael, thank you.